# getcolumntype() function in model.php script giving problem

Tags: cakephp, models

The site that I worked on is working very fine on the test server. I downloaded the same copy and uploaded onto the new server (live). I changed the database.php in app/config folder to set the db connection variables. And I get this following error when I try to open the link.

Cannot access empty property in {serverinformation}/cake/libs/model/model.php on line 1002

I am not able to find any help on this anywhere. Can somebody help me please. I need to get the site live... and I am not sure what could be the problem and where to debug for it.

Comment: Which version of Cake are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Is that the only error message?

Check file permissions on the live server.

Try clearing your cache files - all files in and below `app/tmp/cache`, but leave the directories themselves intact.